# Variable importance in Random Forests returning only 1 value

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, random-forest, data-analysis

I am using Random Forest Classifier to predict the career path to graduate students as my project. I want to print the feature importance and I am getting a single value list where as I have 19 variables. How can I get the variable importance of RF? The output I get here is `[1.]` My code is:

```
traindt=pd.read_csv("Trainingdata11.csv")
testdt=pd.read_csv("Testingdata.csv")
cols= ['age','gender','f_occ','siblings','upb_style','medium','percent_10th','percent_12th','CGPA','loan','type_ins','opentopath','tech_rate','apt_rate','comm_rate','cca_rate','projects','internships','papers']
fin=['path']
trainArr =np.genfromtxt('Trainingdata11.csv',skip_header=1,delimiter=',',dtype=None,filling_values=0,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18))

trainRes = np.genfromtxt('Trainingdata11.csv',skip_header=1,delimiter=',',dtype=None,filling_values=0,usecols=(19))
testArr = np.genfromtxt('Testingdata.csv',skip_header=1,delimiter=',',dtype=None,filling_values=0,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18))
ActRes = np.genfromtxt('Testingdata.csv',skip_header=1,delimiter=',',dtype=None,filling_values=0,usecols=(19))

trainArr= trainArr[:, None]
testArr=testArr[:,None]
trainRes=trainRes[:,None]
ActRes=ActRes[:,None]
rf=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True,oob_score=True,n_estimators=400,
    criterion='gini',max_features='log2',random_state=1)
rf.fit(trainArr,trainRes.ravel())
importances = rf.feature_importances_
print(importances)
```

Comment: Can you please kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the output of `trainArr.shape` ?

Comment: Hey Akshay Nevrekar (590L, 1L) is the value of trainArr.shape

Comment: trainArr1=[]
for i in trainArr:
    for j in i:
        trainArr1.append(list(j))
trainArr1 = pd.get_dummies(traindt[cols])
#algorithm---------------------------------------------------------------
rf=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True,min_samples_leaf=1,oob_score=True,n_estimators=400,
                          max_features='sqrt',min_samples_split=5,max_depth=30)
rf.fit(trainArr1,trainRes.ravel())
imp = rf.feature_importances_
print(imp)    //ValueError: could not convert string to float: Female

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to make it accept various kinds of data types other than label encoding

Comment: I changed it to (590L,19L)  but I am getting the above Value Error to convert string to float.

Comment: maybe you have a variable which is string. remove that variable or use one hot encoding.

Comment: I have strings and integers and float. Cant we find the variable importance directly for strings without using one hot encoding? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Random Forest in sklearn cannot deal with string categoricals, so I'm afraid you are going to have to use some sort of encoding. One hot encoding is generally the accepted way forward.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and suggesstions :)